# Terraform: Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to create EC2 instance in AWS and preparing an Ansible inventory file using resource null_resource
Below is the snippet of the code
In variables.tf for to have different instance types for different env like dev, test and prod am using map function

```
resource "aws_instance" "myec2instace" {
    ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
    #instance_type = var.instance_type_list[1]
    instance_type = var.ispto_service_ec2_inst_type["test"]
    key_name = var.is_pto_service_key_pair
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.pto-ssh.id]
    count = 1
    tags = {
        "Name"  : "PTO-EC2ins-${count.index}"
    }
}

resource "null_resource" "localinventory01" {
    triggers = {
        mytest = timestamp()
    }
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "echo ${aws_instance.myec2instace.*.tags.Name} ansible_host=${aws_instance.myec2instace.*.public_ip} ansible_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/nelbo/Downloads/xxxservice.pem ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22 >> inventory"
      
    }
}
```

terraform validate validated the file successfully and
terraform plan is ran successfully
where when I try to run terraform apply getting

```
│ aws_instance.myec2instace is tuple with 1 element
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Please let me what is wrong am doing in preparing inventory file from *.tfstate file.

Comment: Try with `aws_instance.myec2instace[0].tags.Name`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Still the same issue even after changed as suggested.

Comment: Have you replaced it in both places? This should also be changed to use the index: `ansible_host=${aws_instance.myec2instace[0].public_ip`.

Comment: Yes forgot to do that. Now made change in both the places it worked.     But when i try to prepare inventory file like below mentioned code it worked                    
 resource "local_file" "ip" {
    filename = "host"
    content = <<-EOT
        %{for ip in aws_instance.myec2instace.*.public_ip ~}
        ${ip} ansible_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/nelbo/Downloads/isptoservice.pem ansible_connection=ssh ansible_port=22
        %{endfor ~}
    EOT
}